# react-native-material/core . when i input the text using keybord , label text and my text is overlapping

Tags: react-native

[image]

```
import React from 'react';
import {TextInput} from '@react-native-material/core';
import {View} from '@ant-design/react-native';

const Appss = () => {
  return (
    <View>
      <TextInput label="Label" style={{margin: 16}} />
      <TextInput label="Label" style={{margin: 16}} />
    </View>
  );
};

export default Appss;
```

i use "npm install @react-native-material/core" this packeg
when i input the text using keyboard , label text and my text is overlapping

i expect when keyboard not appear label and my keyboard input text not overlapping.